# Unicorn (4.9.0) + Rails (2.2.2) gives me always the same session_id - Do you know how to fix that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, ruby-on-rails-2

I try to get an old Rails app running with unicorn.

The session is set to :active_record_store

So far so good...

I get on my machine with any browser ALWAYS the same session_id if I go to the app. I set the session_store to :mem_cache_store and I get the same session_id again...

When I start the app via script/server everything is fine, so I think the problem lies in unicorn.

Here is my config.ru

```
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
```

and here is my unicorn.rb

```
app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
tmp_dir = "#{app_dir}/tmp"
working_directory app_dir

# Set unicorn options
worker_processes 2
preload_app true
timeout 3600

# Path for the Unicorn socket
listen "#{tmp_dir}/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

# Set path for logging
stderr_path "#{app_dir}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{app_dir}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

# Set proccess id path
pid "#{tmp_dir}/pids/unicorn.pid"
```

Rails Version 2.2.2
Ruby Version 1.8.7
Unicorn Version 4.9.0

Disclaimer:
I know its an very old version. I know that, my customer knows that - we are already working on the new one. But it would be nice to get that app running.

Answer (score 0):

I took Puma with version 2.16.0 and now everything works fine.